# Symfony2 Redis Validator, string instead of ClassMetadata

Tags: php, symfony, caching, redis, doctrine

I've migrated from Memcached to Redis. At first I was using PECL Redis 3.1.3 and everything works ok. After update to 3.1.5 I start receiving errors:

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Type error:
>   Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Factory\LazyLoadingMetadataFactory::mergeConstraints()
>   must be an instance of
>   Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata, string given,
>   called in
>   /var/www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Factory/LazyLoadingMetadataFactory.php
>   on line 95" at
>   /var/www/acme/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Factory/LazyLoadingMetadataFactory.php
>   line 120

I've looked and redis changelog and didn't find any clue what can be wrong after two version update..

My config.yml (only cache/redis stuff):

```
framework:
    validation:
        cache: validator.mapping.cache.redis
    serializer:
        cache: serializer.mapping.cache.redis
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.redis

doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: redis
            host: "%redis.ip%"
            port: "%redis.port%"
            instance_class: Redis
            class: RedisCache
        query_cache_driver:
            type: redis
            host: "%redis.ip%"
            port: "%redis.port%"
            instance_class: Redis
            class: RedisCache
        result_cache_driver:
            type: redis
            host: "%redis.ip%"
            port: "%redis.port%"
            instance_class: Redis
            class: RedisCache

services:
    serializer.mapping.cache.redis:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache

    validator.mapping.cache.redis:
        class: Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\DoctrineCache
        arguments: ['@doctrine.cache.redis']

    redis:
        class: Redis
        calls:
            - [ connect, [ '%redis.ip%', '%redis.port%' ]]

    doctrine.cache.redis:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache
        calls:
            - [setRedis, ["@redis"]]

    session.handler.redis:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeSessionHandler

    serializer.mapping.cache.memcached:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\MemcachedCache


doctrine_cache:
    providers:
        redis_cache:
            redis:
                connection_id: redis
```

My symfony version is 2.8.31. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

flushing redis solved problem.. silly

```
redis-cli flushall
```